# Putnam B6 1995 Solution

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, elementary-number-theory

Let N be the positive integers. For any α > 0, define Sα = { [nα]: n ∈ N}. Prove that we cannot find α, β, γ such that N = Sα ∪ Sβ ∪ Sγ and Sα, Sβ, Sγ are (pairwise) disjoint.

I'm referring to the solution here: https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol9512.html

Take any integer k > α, β, γ. Let { } denote the fractional part. Then at least two of the $k^3$ + 1 points ({i/α}, {i/β}, {i/γ}), where i = 0, 1, 2, ... , $k^3$, must lie in a cube side 1/k. Suppose they are i > j. Let h = i - j, then for some positive integers a, b, c we have |h/α - a|, |h/β - b|, |h/γ - c| ≤ 1/k. Hence |h - aα|, |h - bβ|, |h - cγ| < 1 (since k > α, β, γ). So each of [aα], [bβ], [cγ] is h or h - 1. Hence two are equal.

**The only confusion I have is from the line:**

Let h = i - j, then for some positive integers a, b, c we have |h/α - a|, |h/β - b|, |h/γ - c| ≤ 1/k.

How is this derived? If you take the difference between two points in the cube, you get |{i/α} - {j/α}| which does not necessarily equal |{h/α}|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not claiming that $\Big|\Big\{\frac{h}{\alpha}\Big\}\Big| = \Big|\Big\{\frac{i}{\alpha}\Big\} - \Big\{\frac{j}{\alpha}\Big\}\Big|$, but rather that $\Big\{\frac{h}{\alpha}\Big\}$ and $\Big\{\frac{i}{\alpha}\Big\} - \Big\{\frac{j}{\alpha}\Big\}$ have the same fractional part, and thus only differ by an integer. This discrepancy is then handled as part of the choosing of $a,b,c$.

Indeed, suppose $\frac{i}{\alpha} = y + \big\{\frac{i}{\alpha}\big\}$ and $\frac{j}{\alpha} = z + \big\{\frac{j}{\alpha}\big\}$ for $y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have $$\left\{\frac{h}{\alpha}\right\} = \left\{\frac{i}{\alpha} - \frac{j}{\alpha}\right\} = \bigg\{y + \Big\{\frac{i}{\alpha}\Big\} - z - \Big\{\frac{j}{\alpha}\Big\}\bigg\} = \bigg\{\Big\{\frac{i}{\alpha}\Big\} - \Big\{\frac{j}{\alpha}\Big\}\bigg\}. $$

But this implies that $\Big\{\frac{i}{\alpha}\Big\} - \Big\{\frac{j}{\alpha}\Big\} = N + \Big\{\frac{h}{\alpha}\Big\}$ for some integer $N$ (in fact, $N$ is either $0$ or $-1$ but we don't need this).